# Dynamically Transform Data with User Input (Highcharts, JavaScript,Django)

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, highcharts, interpolation

I'm passing data as JSON to a Highcharts line chart. There are multiple lines (curves rather) and they have different start and end points - but they all need to be plotted together. As such, my series looks like this, where the "data" is arranged so that they are x,y pairs :

```
series = [{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]], 'name': 'pc1', 'visible': False},
 {'data': [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]], 'name': 'pc2', 'visible': False},
 {'data': [[80, 700], [90, 980]], 'name': 'pc3', 'visible': False}, etc.
```

This data is computed using standard air density. I want to user to be able to enter a different air density, and have the data be available for use with the click of a button (I'm thinking with setData).

Basically, the data is wind speed vs RPM  -  the X values are Wind Speed, and Y are a corresponding RPM. By changing the putting in a new air density, a user will do generate an adjustment factor that will then be used to find the RPM at the new point. So a quick example:

```
Standard Air Density (1.225 kg/m3): 
1 mph 100rpm
2 mph 250rpm
3 mph 500rpm
```

Now we compute an adjustment factor with new air density (assume 1.5 kg/m3) with the formula adj_factor = (new air density/1.225)^(1/3) -> this returns 1.07. With this factor, I can calculate the new rpm by just taking power at the wind speed * adjustment factor and interpolating the data.

```
New Air Density (1.5 kg/m3)
1 mph, (whatever RPM is @ 1.07mph (1mph*adj factor))
2 mph, (whatever RPM is @ 2.14mph (1mph*adj factor))
3 mph, (whatever RPM is @ 3.21mph (1mph*adj factor))
```

The problem I'm running into is that I'm a very inexperienced in JS and don't quite understand how to dynamically create data, or how to reference the old curves Y values with the adjusted windspeeds.

To do this know that I have to interpolate data - which i've done using numpy.

Is there a way to apply this transformation from the JavaScript side? My chart is a standard HighCharts line chart of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart_id).highcharts({
chart: chart,
title: title,
credits: credits,
xAxis: {},
yAxis: yAxis,
legend: legend,
series: series

});
```

and in my Django Views i'm defining all the parameters:

```
chart  = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height,}
title  = {"text": 'Power Curves'}
yAxis  = {"title": {"text": 'Output (RPM)'}}
series = json.dumps(series_)
```

And the series of the form mentioned earlier. THe graph works fine - it's the dynamic loading of the data and implementation of the adjustment factor that I am struggling with.

Thanks

Comment: You could get current data from series using [`Series.options`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.options) and in returned object access data as `options.data`. Then change the data and apply to series using `Series.setData()`. If you will have problems with that, please provide a live demo, e.g. in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

define 3 arrays of data in javascript and on button click change the values in the arrays and set the new values to highcharts using setData